# javascript regex match word not followed by pattern with text inbetween

Tags: javascript, regex

text:

```
id="word1 word2 word3/343/els/425/word4 word5 word6"
wordA wordB Bword2B word1 word2 word3
blah blah blah
```

i'm trying to match the whole words: **word1, word2, word3** in the text BUT i don't want them matched in the `id="word1 word2 word3/343/els/425/word4 word5 word6"` line of the text, the words are not in latin.

**current approach:**

```
var sWord = "word2";
text = text.replace( new RegExp(sWord+"(?!\/[0-9])", "gi"), "<span style='background-color: yellow'>"+sWord+"</span>");
```

this approach only works for word3, not for word1 or word2, so how do I introduce in the regex the possibility that before the NUMBER,there is another word?

```
"(?!.\/[0-9])"
```

i added the dot "." to the regex. but it doesn't seem to work.

Plus, how do I add the possibility for whole word match? **\b** and **\S** don't seem to work, because words are not in latin.

thank you in advance!

**EDIT:**
jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/GLt4F/5/

as you can see the button breaks for word1 and word2 but not for word3 because the match is correct

**EDIT2:**

rephrasing the problem: match AAA ONLY if not followed by BBB and between them can be anything. for example:

AAA frefe BBB should not be matched

AAA BBB should not be matched

AAA frefe cc should be matched

Comment: Any chance we can get a jsfiddle that we can use to test possible solutions to this :)

Comment: Not sure about the others, but I can't understand what you re trying to achieve. What do u mean with "i don't want them matched in the "id=blahblah"". word1 will never match blahblah. Better explanation needed

Comment: Why not strip away `id="..."` before pattern matching?

Comment: @VladL the text is an HTML before being displayed. so i want to highlight word2 in the html, but i don't want to change it in the id="word1 etc." because it will break javascript functionality. blahblah is short for the whole line i posted.

Comment: @BogdanKulynych i can't strip it because it's part of the text variable which is actually HTML to be displayed.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GLt4F/5/

as you can see the button breaks for word1 and word2 but not for word3 because the match is correct

Comment: do you mean something like that? http://jsfiddle.net/PBu7S/

Comment: @salexch: Your solution will fail when the input is only text.

Comment: @nhahtdh it wasn't a solution.. but you are right.
otherwise I would post it as an answer

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: This is a not so clean solution. In fact, it is ugly as hell IMO, not sure what I was thinking when I try to solve it this way... http://jsfiddle.net/GLt4F/10/

Comment: i'm not good at regexes, but theoretically it seems simple: find pattern AAA but not if after AAA there is pattern BBB like this AAA*BBB where * can be anything.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: A proper(?) JS solution: http://jsfiddle.net/GLt4F/15/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?!(.*)\/[0-9])
```

this seems to do the trick ( for not matching when something is in between. don't know if there are loopholes or if it's a solid answer though.

Answer (score 3):

```
/AAA([\s\S](?!=BBB))*$/
```

should do it.

> Plus, how do I add the possibility for whole word match? \b and \S don't seem to work, because words are not in latin.

JavaScript doesn't have a unicode compatibility mode, so you have to write your own character set for a word char and use negative matching, so

```
(?:^|[^A-Za-z0-9_$])
```

before the AAA, and there's no lookbehind in JS so the previous non-word char will be part of captured group 0.